# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'domainId'

Tags: powershell

I do not understand why I am getting this error, concerning one of my parameters

```
Function Testing{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod] $Method = [WebRequestMethod]::Get,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [String] $DomainId = $false,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [System.Collections.IDictionary] $Header
    )
    $parameters = @{}
    $parameters["domainId"] = $DomainId

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod @parameters
    $result
    exit
}
# ...
$header =@{Authorization="Bearer $AuthToken"}
Testing -DomainId "test" -Header $header -Method Get
```

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod @parameters` -> `Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Header -Body $parameters`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I get " Missing an argument for parameter 'Body'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object' and try again."

Comment: Don't forget to pass `$parameters` as the `-Body` argument (comment line wrapped around)